# Is this the best way to collapse a column width?

Tags: html, css

Requirements:
When the page (or in the case of the example Frame) expands, the only column to expand with the table should be 'unfrozen' columns (without the 'freeze' class).

[here is the live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BZDyr/4/) *The jQuery is there to show dynamic content, it is not the code under review*

What I really don't like is that is seems to hacky to just set the width of the column to 1px... I can forsee this causing issues with older/junkier browsers.

**HTML**

```
<!-- snippet -->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="freeze">id</th>
            <th class="freeze">name</th>
            <th>description</th>
            <th class="freeze">something else</th>
            <th class="freeze">actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

**CSS**

```
.data-table {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 90%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #666;
}
.data-table th {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}
.data-table td {
    font-size: 90%;
    color: #222;   
}
.data-table td:last-child {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.data-table td, .data-table th {
    padding: 6px;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
}
.data-table td:last-child, .data-table th:last-child {
    border: none; 
}
.data-table tbody tr {
    border: 1px solid #666; 
}
.data-table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color: #efefef;
}
.freeze {
    width: 1px;   
}
```

This works in at least IE8, Chrome 16, and FF8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO it's completely fine to set the width like this. Table cell widths have always be defined to be a "minimum width".

As long the table doesn't have `table-layout: fixed` or the cells don't have `overflow` set to anything else than `visible`, I don't believe any browser (old or new) would have any problems width this.

The only nitpick I would have, it that the size of `1px` feels wrong to me, mostly because this forces the column to wrap as much as possible and depending on the content this may not look very good. I would suggest `1em` (purely because it "feels" better :-) and maybe a larger minimal width such as `10em` would be suitable for some columns.